# Remove port from url with nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have 2 instances of a website running on the same server for dev and staging environments on docker containers. The source codes for these sites are same but in 2 separate folders. **/dev** and **/uat** on the same server and they could be accessed through a single domain but different ports i.e. **dev.website.com:5000** and **dev.website.com**

I do not have access to the DNS and can't change it but I requested to have a domain **uat.website.com** pointed to the same IP address so I could remove that port. Is this possible through reverse proxy or would it require DNS changes?

**PROBLEM**

dev - dev.website.com:5000

uat - dev.website.com

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACHIEVE**

dev - dev.website.com

uat - uat.website.com

**docker-compose dev.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  dev_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  web_dev:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: web_dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - app_dev
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    networks:
      - dev_network

  app_dev:
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    container_name: app_dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9005:9000"
    networks:
      - dev_network
```

**docker-compose uat.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  uat_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  web_uat:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: web_uat
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.uat.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - app_uat
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - uat_network

  app_uat:
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    container_name: app_uat
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - uat_network
```

**nginx conf for dev**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root    /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app_dev:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**nginx conf for uat**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root    /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app_uat:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the easiest way to achieve virtual host routing is to use [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/) with docker compose. It will handle the redirection for you and can also terminate https if needed (Given you can access the same server via different dns names.) . You can certainly also add another layer of nginx as reverse proxy.